# Copy and Paste in WMware Fusion 8.5

Tags: macos, vmware, copy-paste, isolation, vmware-fusion

I try to enable copy and paste between my host (Debian on Vmware Fusion) and my Macbook Pro.
I've follwing some steps to activate this function in settings ''isolation'', then I reboot VMware to see but nothing change.

Someone having this problem or know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that VMware tools is installed in your Debian VM. Also, try rebooting your host computer (MacBook Pro) after.

Answer (score 0):

In VMware Fusion, right click on the name of VM -> Click on settings -> Isolation.

If "Enable Drag and Drop" and "Enable Copy and Paste" are enabled in the "Isolation" settings You need to install VMware tools. You may refer to

https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1022525

or go through video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ueM1dCk3o58&feature=youtu.be